# <a> onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, html

My function is not fired when the  tag is clicked. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="footer">
    <div data-role="tabstrip" id="tabs"> 
        <a href="views/contacts.html" data-icon="home" id="home">Home</a>  
        <a href="views/settings.html" data-icon="settings" id="settings">Settings</a>
        <a onclick="signOff()" href="views/home.html" data-icon="settings" id="contacts">Log Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function signOff() {
    console.log("something");
    VCare.VCareWebService.signOff({cache:false,
        callback:function(xml) { // invoke the service
            // use jQuery to extract information we are interested in
            console.log(xml);
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Please include a minimal example that reproduces the problem, a clear problem statement, and any error messages or other information to help identify the problem. Without this information, it is hard to answer the question.

Comment: @bjb568  There are no error messages as the method does not get fired. I just need to call the function "signOff()" in the onclick and it is not being called. That code is all there is to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have both an `onClick` function and valid `href` attribute in `<a>`.
Change your anchor element to:

```
<a onclick="signOff()" href="javascript:void(0)" data-icon="settings" id="contacts">Log Out</a>
```

You can redirect the page using javascript if you want to.

Comment: Thanks. That works if I delete the href attribute. It had an error with that exact code. I will mark as answer when allowed.

Comment: Glad to be of help, @btf217! Please do mark as answer when you can. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to make sure that your `onclick` returns a false to stop the default event from running.

```
<a onclick="signOff(); return false" href="views/home.html" data-icon="settings" id="contacts">Log Out</a>
```

Or..

```
<a onclick="return signOff();" href="views/home.html" data-icon="settings" id="contacts">Log Out</a>

function signOff() {
    console.log("something");
    VCare.VCareWebService.signOff({cache:false,
        callback:function(xml) { // invoke the service
            // use jQuery to extract information we are interested in
            console.log(xml);
        }
   });

   return false;
}
```

Comment: This works great for confirm box case:  "return confirm('r u sure?')"

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your A tag to

```
<a  href="javascript:signOff();
window.location = "views/home.html" data-icon="settings" id="contacts">Log Out</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not using the onclick method. Not only does it apparently conflict with the default href operation, but it can also cause some minor visual issues where clicking in the margins of the element, etc., can call the function without highlighting the text the way you would expect in a normal link.

Instead, use:

```
<a  href="javascript:signOff()" data-icon="settings" id="contacts">Log Out</a>
```

Then just change the page address programatically in the `signOff` function, using `this.document.location.href = location` or similar

EDIT: it's looking like window.location works better.  +1 for Omar, looks like he has the same answer